# How to turn on track_commit_timestamp in psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-TRACK-COMMIT-TIMESTAMP

> track_commit_timestamp (boolean) Record commit time of transactions.
> This parameter can only be set in postgresql.conf file or on the
> server command line. The default value is off.

`show track_commit_timestamp;` return off.
How to turn on in psql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ALTER SYSTEM` as a superuser:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET track_commit_timestamp = on;
```

This is equivalent to changing `postgresql.conf`.

You have to restart PostgreSQL to make the new setting effective.

Comment: On my newly installed (from source - fedora 35) 14.1 instance, PG_RELOAD_CONF() will turn it off, but not back on! `ALTER SYSTEM SET track_commit_timestamp = on;` then reload and then `SELECT name, setting, unit, short_desc, pending_restart FROM pg_settings WHERE name like '%track_commit%';` - the pending restart field is still set to true! IMHO, if it works one way, then it should work in "reverse gear"?

Comment: My answer was wrong. I have fixed it.